# Kafka Streams achieve exctly once even when producer restarts

Tags: spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a KafkaStreams applications with exactly_once_v2 guarantee in springboot.

In this two apps :

- App1: Reads from topic  "A" , process and writes to topic "B".
- App2 Reads from topic "B" and writes to topic "C".

The App1 takes too long time to process one record  due a MongoDB temporally problem but finally writes in topic B.
The App2 receives the data correctly from topic B  and writes in topic "C".

The problem is that the App1 takes a long time to process and this causes the producer to restart (
even though the producer finally manages to write) this invalidates the previous producer (InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch) and creates a new one.

The new one reads again the same message and writes it in the topic with the new producer so we end up with duplication. App2 reads the same message again produced by the new producer.

I thought that exactly once prevents of this kind of situations.

I'm using Kafka Streams 3.2.0

Is there a way to prevent a producer restart from writing the same message twice to the topic?.

I hope that the messages are not duplicated even if the producer is restarted.
I tried setting it to exactly once but it doesn't work for this case

Answer (score 0):

If the producer fails, the corresponding transaction will be aborted. While the messages are physically still in the output topic, they are marked as "aborted".

A downstream consumer must be configured with `isolation.level="read_committed"` to filter aborted messages.

If you have a downstream Kafka Streams application, you can do the same. If the downstream Kafka Streams application is using exaclty-once processing guarantees, it will automatically use `"read_committed"` mode and you don't need to do anything in addition.

> due a MongoDB temporally problem

Btw: if you are using EOS and an external dependency like MongoDB, you don't get exactly-once guarantees, because side effects like accessing MongoDB are not guarded.